# Why Doesn't The Time Display?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var currentTime = new Date();

var futureTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime());
futureTime.setMinutes(futureTime.getMinutes() + 10);

var pastTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime());
pastTime.setMinutes(pastTime.getMinutes() - 50);
</script>
```

all I'm trying to do is if the current time is `6:00PM`, to display 50 minutes before then which is `5:10PM` and I'm also trying to display another time 10 minutes after the current time which is `6:10PM`..  How do I do this so it is formatted exactly as `X:XXPM`?

I put the above code into my page and I see nothing at all..

Comment: All you're doing is setting variables. What do you expect to see?

Comment: Look at [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write)

Comment: @JasonSperske what? No, don't encourage document.write. Print to a div or something!

Comment: You wouldn't see anything, you're not outputting anything, such as with console.log.  Regardless, you are trying to call setMinutes on the numeric value that is returned by a Javascript date's getTime() method -- you want to be calling setMinutes on the data object itself.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @Mathletics, for my own code I 100% agree, but it seemed like an easy place to start with minimal understanding of the DOM :)

Comment: @Mathletics Even with `document.write(pastTime)` it displays as `Wed Oct 09 2013 12:02:33 GMT-0400 (EDT)` so how do I just get the simple `X:XXPM`? but I see you are saying to print to a div so how would that be done?

Comment: [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) will do amazing things with dates and times if you don't want to understand how to format them by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send the values to some HTML elements:

HTML:

```
<p id="future"></p>
<p id="past"></p>
```

Javascript:

```
function formatTime(dateObj){

    var dateString = "";
    var hour = dateObj.getHours();  
    var minutes = dateObj.getMinutes();
    var pm = false;

    if (hour > 12)
        pm = true;

    if (pm === true){
        var pmHour = (hour>=13) ? hour-12:hour;
        dateString += pmHour.toString();
        dateString += ":";
        dateString += minutes.toString();
        dateString += " pm";
    }

    else{
        dateString += hour.toString();
        dateString += ":";
        dateString += minutes.toString();
        dateString += " am";
    }

    return dateString;
}

var currentTime = new Date();

var futureTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime());
futureTime.setMinutes(futureTime.getMinutes() + 10);
var f = document.getElementById("future");
f.innerHTML = formatTime(futureTime);

var pastTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime());
pastTime.setMinutes(pastTime.getMinutes() - 50);
var f = document.getElementById("past");
f.innerHTML = formatTime(pastTime);
```

**[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tylerpachal/4WWWa/)**

Comment: this seems like a good solution but how do I output only `X:XXPM` instead of something like `Wed Oct 09 2013 12:08:38 GMT-0400 (EDT)`?

Comment: @JoeBobby updated my answer/example with a JS function which formats the time

Comment: @just updated it again, it wouldn't have displayed 12:xxpm correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.write(currentTime + '<br>' + futureTime + '<br>' + pastTime);
```

or

```
var str = currentTime + '<br>' + futureTime + '<br>' + pastTime;
document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML = str;
```

or

```
var str = currentTime + '<br>' + futureTime + '<br>' + pastTime;
document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(str);
```

or

```
document.getElementById('myDiv1').appendChild(pastTime);
document.getElementById('myDiv2').appendChild(currentTime);
document.getElementById('myDiv3').appendChild(futureTime);
```

and your html would look like

```
<div id='myDiv1'></div>
<div id='myDiv2'></div>
<div id='myDiv3'></div>
```

#### UPDATE

To format dates - that is a different question - and is already answered by countless posts.

[Here's a great one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

or

[10 ways to format time and date using JavaScript.](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3)

#### NOTE

Jason Sperske made a comment I couldn't ignore - [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is amazing.

Comment: Even with `document.write(pastTime)` it displays as `Wed Oct 09 2013 12:02:33 GMT-0400 (EDT)` so how do I just get the simple `X:XXPM`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
var currentTime = new Date();

var futureTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime());
futureTime.setMinutes(futureTime.getMinutes() + 10);

var pastTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime());
pastTime.setMinutes(pastTime.getMinutes() - 50);

function formatAMPM(date) {
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  return strTime;
}


alert('Current Time: ' + formatAMPM(currentTime));

alert('Future Time: ' + formatAMPM(futureTime));

alert('Past Time: ' + formatAMPM(pastTime));
```

Try it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/atheos/Wx2vw/